# Tweetr AS3 logout function?

Tags: twitter, actionscript, air

i'm making a program which used twitter connect as its core and it is developed with adobe AIR, the library i used it Tweetr, and everything is perfect until i don't find any example on how to logout and login again. I've used tweetr.destroy() and tweetr.endSession() but there is no effect in the program. Now i'm in very desperate situation, would thanks  to anyone that can help me through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no way to log a user out using Tweetr, because the Twitter API does not provide a method for this.  If you need to log in again, you can simply restart the oAuth process, or alternatively you could try pinging http://twitter.com/logout with URLloader to log you current user out of Twitter.  This is the URL used on the oAuth popup when the user wishes to change account before authorising an app.

`endSession` only ends your current API session.

Comment: this works for me !, but it was not a convinient way to do so

Answer (score 0):

Try tweetr.endSession()

As per the Tweetr documentation:

> `public function endSession():void`
>
> Ends the session of the authenticating user. and Returns a HashData object with the response.
>
> This method requires Authentication

http://tweetr.swfjunkie.com/docs/

Comment: heh, sorry, I just re-read your question and saw that endSession() is not working for you

Answer (score 0):

Know this is old. But will post the answer anyway.

Try this: `htmlLoader.manageCookies=false;`

Works for me:

```
htmlLoader = HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(false, null, true, new Rectangle(0,0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight));
htmlLoader.stage.nativeWindow.alwaysInFront = true;
htmlLoader.manageCookies=false;
addChild(htmlLoader);

oauth.oauthToken=new String();
oauth.oauthTokenSecret=new String();
oauth.htmlLoader = htmlLoader;
oauth.getAuthorizationRequest();
```